# How can I improve my wireless connection?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, pci

I recently built a machine running Ubuntu 14.04 using a TP-Link TL-WDN4800 PCI wireless network adapter. When I click on the wireless connection icon on the Ubuntu taskbar, it almost always tells me that my connection speed is 54 Mb/s or thereabouts. In actuality, my download speed occasionally dips below 1 Mb/s, and certainly never surpasses 2 Mb/s. I have a NETGEAR WNDR3400 router. I want to improve my connection speed, as right now some online games are unplayable and Firefox has crashed multiple times. Help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are you getting the tested speeds from?

Comment: Browsers don't generally crash because of slow connection speeds. Unless you're confusing stalled-out page loads for crashes.

Comment: elevate the router to a high location in the room if you can, you did not mention where both devices were in relation to each other or how far.

Comment: The router is on the ground floor of my house, but my computer is on the second story.

Comment: Also, does the position of the antennae affect anything?

Answer (score 1):

- Pick a cleaner channel.
- Clean up whatever channel you pick, by disabling or moving other devices that use that frequency band.
- Move closer to the router. But not too close. Less than 1m is probably too close.
- Make sure your card's antennas are connected well and positioned well, away from interference (PC, display, display cable) and obstructions.
- Keep the case on your PC. Part of the case's job is to reduce electromagnetic interference from your PCs boards from interfering with your radios.
- Make sure to use only WPA2 (AES-CCMP) security. No WEP or WPA (TKIP). Only WPA2 is fast enough for 802.11n data rates. Clients will only connect in up-to-54Mbps 802.11a/g speeds if only WEP or only WPA (TKIP) is available.
- Make sure WMM (wireless QoS) is enabled. 802.11n requires WMM. Disabling it disables 802.11n.
- Make sure you've enabled 20/40MHz channel mode. 20MHz-only mode cuts your bandwidth in half, and 40MHz-only mode is nonstandard.
- Contrary to a popular myth, you should NOT use 802.11n-only mode. Go ahead and leave the a/b/g rates enabled alongside the N rates. 802.11n devices need the ability to use those legacy rates at times. Just make sure to get rid of any old a/b/g devices you still use, or upgrade them to N.
- Consider upgrading your AP. Your AP only supports 2 spatial streams, so its maximum signaling rate is 300Mbps. Your card supports 3 spatial streams, so it could do 450Mbps signaling if it had a 3-stream-capable AP to talk to.

Comment: On Ubuntu, where would I go to change channel, etc?

Comment: The channel is set by the AP. As are most of the settings I mentioned.

Comment: Why Ubuntu is providing much slower speed than windows?

Comment: @Sachith OP didn't say anything about Windows. If you have a question about Ubuntu being slower than Windows, post your own Question and document your own situation.

Comment: In my AP, there is a "mode" option, and the settings I can choose from are "Up to 54 Mb/s" "Up to 145 Mb/s" and "Up to 300 Mb/s". Would there be any drawback to changing this from the first option to the third?

Comment: Also, can my device connect to one channel while other devices are connected to another?

Comment: @evandewey Judging from the speeds, those modes are basically "A/B/G mode", "A/B/G/N mode but only 20MHz-wide channels", and "A/B/G/N mode with 20/40MHz-wide channels", respectively. For the 5GHz radio, I'd set it to the "Up to 300 Mb/s" so it's enabling full speed with 40MHz-wide channels. For the 2.4GHz radio, I might leave it at "Up to 145 Mb/s" so I'm only using a 20MHz-wide channel, leaving room for Bluetooth and other 2.4GHz non-Wi-Fi devices to share that crowded 2.4GHz band.

Comment: @evandewey And yes, your Netgear WNDR3400 router services both b/g/n in the 2.4GHz band and a/n in the 5GHz band simultaneously. When I say, "pick a clean channel", it means pick a clean channel for each band.